# jQuery: Is it possible to use a getJSON request inside another getJSON request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

Is it possible to use a getJSON request inside another getJSON request, using jQuery?

Something like this:

```
// Population the Requests List
// jQuery AJAX call for JSON
$.getJSON( '/workspace/friends/sentRequests', function( data ) {
    // For each item in our JSON, add a table row and cells to the content string
    $.each(data, function(){
        //Loading each user data into global variable.
        $.getJSON( '/workspace/friends/' + this.friendId, function( user ) {
            requestListData.push(user);
        });

        requestTableContent += '<tr>';
        requestTableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser btn btn-info btn-xs"" rel="' + this.friendId + '" title="Show Details">' + this.name + '</td>';
        requestTableContent += '<td><a href="mailto:' + this.email + '">' + this.email + '</a></td>';
        requestTableContent += '<td>' + moment(useListData[-1].activity.date_established).format('MMMM Do YYYY') + '</td>';
        requestTableContent += '<td>' + this.gender + '</td>';
        requestTableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkdeleteuser btn btn-danger btn-xs" rel="' + this.email + '">Danger!</a></td>';
    });

    // Inject the whole content string into our existing HTML table
    $('#requestList table tbody').html(requestTableContent);
});
```

I was wondering if this is possible? And if so what I'm doing wrong here...

***EDIT:*** I'm asking this because it should populate a table with the data from the getJSON requests but it's not.

Comment: How do you know you're doing something wrong? There's no "inside" to an asynchronous request like that; the callback function is just a function and it can do anything any other function can do.

Comment: explain what's not working as expected

Comment: Yes, it's possible but it shows bad design: if you're calling a web service to get data then design it so that you just get everything back in one request. Here it looks like there's a new request for every row: just get the whole table once instead of one row at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. You're executing the two requests in *series* here - the second will not be executed until the first returns. This is necessary because the inner request depends on the outer request's response.

If you control the server, you could almost certainly make your application more efficient by returning the combined data from a single request.

In circumstances where the second request doesn't depend on the first, you could make the requests in *parallel* using [jQuery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), which waits for the completion of several  [promises](http://12devs.co.uk/articles/promises-an-alternative-way-to-approach-asynchronous-javascript/)

```
var first = $.getJSON({  ... });
var second = $.getJSON({  ... });


$.when(first, second)
  .done(function(firstResult, secondResult) {
     // Executed when both requests complete successfully
     // Both results are available here 
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // Executed if at least one request fails
  })
```

[jQuery promise documentation](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Comment: And what If I want to have the second in a cycle using the first one with $.each(), should I save it in a temp first? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can execute any **JavaScript** code inside the callback function of your first request.